# ElasticSearch how to search by 2 level nested items?

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I have this kind of data structure

```
[
    {
        id:1,
        translations: [
           {
               language: {id:1; name: "English"},
               value: "How are you ?"
           },
           {
               language: {id:2; name: "French"},
               value: "Comment allez-vous ?"
           },
           ...
        ]
    },
    ...
]
```

so now I want to make a query which will be search the word only in English translations and not in French or another one. And if user types "Comment allez-vous" he won't see any result.

and here is config.yml

```
        index_name: %es.index_name%
        types:
            vocabularyItem:
                mappings:
                    translations:
                        type: "nested"
                        properties:
                            value: {boost: 5}
                            definition: {boost: 2}
                            alternativeTranslations:
                                type: "nested"
                                properties:
                                    value: ~
                            language:
                                type: "nested"
                                properties:
                                    id:
                                        type : integer
                persistence:
                    driver: orm
                    model: Bundle\Model\VocabularyItem
                    provider:
                        batch_size: 100
                    listener:
                        immediate: ~
                    finder: ~
```

Comment: Hello Hayk, can you show your yaml mapping configuration, under "for_elastica:" ?

Comment: Hello @Elyass, just updated the post. have a look please

Comment: thank you. Please have a look at nested queries https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html, I'll prepare an answer for your issue

Answer (score 0):

first of all I recommend you to use a custom Repository. It's just a class witch search functions. This is useful for keeping your controller clean.

In your elastica config :

```
types:
    vocabularyItem:
        mappings:
            ...
        persistence:
            ...
            repository: AppBundle\SearchRepository\VocabularyItemRepository
```

Then in your controller (assuming your index's name is app)

```
$vocabularyItemRepo = $this->get('fos_elastica.repository_manager')->getRepository('app/vocabularyItem');
$results = $vocabularyItemRepo->searchEnglish($keywords);
```

And finally the interesting part, the repository with the query

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\SearchRepository;

use FOS\ElasticaBundle\Repository;
... //other use

class VocabularyItemRepository extends Repository
{
    public function searchEnglish($keywords)
    {
        $query = new BoolQuery();

        $englishQuery = new Match();
        $englishQuery->setField('translations.language.name', 'English');
        $query->addMust($englishQuery);

        $keywordsQuery = new Match();
        $keywordsQuery->setField('yourKeyWordField', $keywords);
        $query->addMust($keywordsQuery);

        return $this->find($query);
    }
}
```

Please try this and tell me if something is wrong